# spoilers - javascript + html

Tags: javascript, html

I need a little help here...
I got "some.js" with classic:

```js
function somequotes() {
  var quotes = new Array()

  quotes[0]='some text'
  quotes[1]='some more text'
  //...
  //...

  var whichquote = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));

  document.write(quotes[whichquote])}
}

somequotes();
```

and "some.html":

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="some.js"></script>
```

It's about jokes and I need some of quotes to be hidden (like spoilers) because some are 18+ ...

So if:

```
quotes[4] = 'some 18+ text'
```

what is best script to hide some of quotes?

Comment: Do you mean that if `Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length)) == 4` you want to show another quote?

Comment: You probably want to apply an array.filter prior to selecting a random quot then.

Comment: Nope - just to hide that quote with link or button with 18+ and to show on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With a single list

If you have the list of offending quotes:

```
function somequotes() {
  var quotes = new Array()

  quotes[0]='some text'
  quotes[1]='some more text'
  //...

  quotes[2]='some 18+ text'

  // Here you specify the list of offensive questions
  offensive = [2];

  var whichquote = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
  var quote = quotes[whichquote];

  if (offensive.indexOf(whichquote) == -1)
    document.write(quotes[whichquote]);
  else
    document.write('<p id="quote-wrap"><button id="quote" data-text="' + quote + '">Reveal</button></p>');
}

function revealer() {
  var quoteWrap = document.getElementById("quote-wrap");
  var quote = document.getElementById("quote");
  if (quoteWrap) {
    quote.addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
      quoteWrap.innerHTML = quote.getAttribute('data-text');
    }, false);
  }
}

somequotes();
revealer();
```

---

### Separating the list

You can too separate the list in two:

```js
quotes_normal = [
    'some text',
    'some more text'
];

quotes_nsfw = [
    'some 18+ text'
];
```

And then generate a list based in whether or not user can view 18+ quotes:

```
if (is_adult)
    var quotes = quotes_normal.concat(quotes_nsfw);
else
    var quotes = quotes_normal;

var whichquote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
var quotetext = quotes[whichquote];
```

Comment: There is more than 1.2k quotes for now and I wish to add some script to hide some quotes

Comment: And do you have the list of offensive quotes? In that case in which format?

Comment: No - there is 1200 randomly added quotes and I would like to add some script like:  quotes[4] [18+]= 'some 18+ text' and if (18+) hide text. On click link or button to show it. I don't want to make new script from scratch...

Comment: You need to know which questions are 18+. For example `offending = [4]` or just separating them like in my reply. If you have the list in an array or if it's just the 4th, I can update the reply and include the code to show the text.

Comment: I dont want to separate them, just to review and add some code to 18+ to hide and add a button to show it like spoilers in forums. And I need that code in existing "some.js"

Comment: I can write an example for the case the offensive question is the 4th with the button to reveal. Would it suit you?

Comment: Can You write an example if 4th, 8th and 15th are offensive and I'll try to adjust it...

Comment: There you go! For your example you just have to replace with `offensive = [4, 8, 15]`

Comment: Nice and if I want that "Reval" be a button what change in script is?

Comment: I changed the reply to display a button. You can stylize further with css.

Comment: Thanks a lot David

Comment: Any time! My pleasure.